# How do I separate Makefile build outputs for different configurations?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, continuous-integration, gnu-make

Given I have a project with a straightforward Makefile like so:

```
all: foobar
foobar: foo.o bar.o
```

that I can build to target different architectures:

```
$ CC=clang make                    # or
$ CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  make  # or
$ CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc make
```

This works but I want to be able to maintain outputs for multiple configurations at the same time, for example on a build server.

What would be a good, clean way to go about this? I've considered the following:

- Use autotools or another build tool, but I want to see what's possible without
- Create build directories with Makefiles in them that set VPATH and include the root Makefile
- Write a script that moves the output after building each architecture
- Modify the Makefile to build multiple configurations. I don't like this solution because you end up with a sort of meta-Makefile that's complex and tightly coupled to your specific build environment
- Add a variable to the Makefile to set the output directory. This could work but it means I can't use implicit Makefile rules. Pattern rules would get messy too

Comment: When you say you want to save the output, do you mean the objects, or just the final executable?   It's common practice to set `$(OBJDIR)` to be the output directory for objects, and you can conditionally set this based on the build configuration.   The implicit rules are pretty simple to rewrite, though you do have to make a rule to create $(OBJDIR) in the first place.

Comment: I think you should use different targets (with directories) to each architecture. Say `arm/foo`, `x86_64/foo` and `main/foo`. I suggest try to be as simple as you can :)

Comment: I think that I'll go with the `$(OBJDIR)` solution mentioned by @John. I was really hoping for something like `make -f ../Makefile VPATH=…` to be possible but I suppose it isn't. @uzsoft I don't think the Makefile should have knowledge of these different environments, instead it should be adaptable. Hence my 'meta-Makefile' remark.

Comment: You could easily make `OBJDIR` configurable on the command line:  `make OBJDIR=/foo/bar`, and then in the makefile do a `OBJDIR ?= /foo/obj-default`, in case the user didn't specify it.   You could even do something like `OBJDIR ?= /foo/obj-$(CC)` if you don't mind ugly directory names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with something like that:

```
# User configuration
BINARY  := hello
SOURCES := main.c

# Create the output paths
out     ?= out
outdir  := $(out)/$(CC)
outbin  := $(outdir)/$(BINARY)
objects := $(outdir)/$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

# Default target
all: $(outbin)

# Binary target
$(outbin): $(objects)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

# Objects target
$(objects): $(outdir)/%.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

# The cleanning targets
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(outdir)

mrproper:
    $(RM) -r $(out)

# Declare phony targets
.PHONY: all clean mrproper
```

Note that the objects target is using [static pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) to be able to get the source files in the current directory and the object files in the output directory.

---

It is also as easy to use as a basic `Makefile`:

```sh
$ make
mkdir -p out/cc
cc -o out/cc/main.o -c main.c
cc -o out/cc/hello out/cc/main.o

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

$ tree
.
├── main.c
├── Makefile
└── out
    └── cc
        ├── hello
        └── main.o

2 directories, 4 files

$ CC=gcc make
mkdir -p out/gcc
gcc -o out/gcc/main.o -c main.c
gcc -o out/gcc/hello out/gcc/main.o

$ tree
.
├── main.c
├── Makefile
└── out
    ├── cc
    │   ├── hello
    │   └── main.o
    └── gcc
        ├── hello
        └── main.o

3 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I think this is the direction I'll go in. If no other fresh ideas come up in the meantime I'll mark this as the answer in a little while.

Comment: One follow up question though: is it possible to do the `obj/%.o: %.c` rule in the classic suffix syntax?

Comment: @SijmenMulder Yes I believe you can. I prefer this notation because it is valid only for the targets you've  specified.

Comment: One quick comment, don't run `mkdir -p` in the recipe for every object.  Instead add the lines `$(objects) : | $(outdir)` and `$(outdir) : ; mkdir -p $@`, which will only run mkdir once.

Comment: @John Your solution is working well only if all your source files are in the same directory. Else you can run `mkdir -p` every times or if you want something cleaner you can check [my other response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43227047/2893600).