# makefile: pattern rules for subdirectory

Tags: c++, makefile, pattern-matching

Here is my project:

```
project
  |--- main.cpp
  |--- makefile
  |--- test
        |--- Test.cpp
        |--- Test.h
```

Here is the `makefile`:

```
g++1x:=g++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -MMD -MP
cflags:= -Wall -lncurses

PATHS:=./ ./test/
TARGET:=matrix.out
SRC:=$(foreach PATH,$(PATHS),$(wildcard $(PATH)/*.cpp))
OBJDIR:=.obj
OBJ:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o)))


.PHONY: install
install: $(OBJDIR) $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(g++1x) $(cflags) -o $@ $^ -g


$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(g++1x) -c -o $@ $< -g

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: ./test/%.cpp
    $(g++1x) -c -o $@ $< -g

-include $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.d)))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

It works well but I have two questions:
1) Is it possible to avoid `foreach` for `PATHS` so that I can use the same `makefile` for all of cpp projects?
2) As you see, to generate `main.o` and `Test.o` I write two blocks:
`$(OBJDIR)/%.o: ./test/%.cpp` and `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp`.
Is it possible to write only once?
I've tried as below but it doesn't work:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(foreach PATH,$(PATHS),$(wildcard $(PATH)/%.cpp))
        $(g++1x) -c -o $@ $< -g
```

I've even tried like this but it doesn't work still:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp ./test/%.cpp
    $(g++1x) -c -o $@ $< -g
```

Comment: Note that your use of an "OBJDIR" is rather ... clumsy. You might enjoy reading [How Not to use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) and [Multi-Architecture Builds](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/multi-architecture-builds/), were the framework provided in the later link can also be used to perform an out-of-source build (which seems to be what you want).

Comment: Have a look at my project https://github.com/cppfw/prorab it solves many problems already, so no need to reinvent own `makefile` template.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should keep the source tree into your object tree. This way it will be easier to create *global* rules and keep dependencies.

```makefile
# Use the shell find command to get the source tree
SOURCES := $(shell find * -type f -name "*.c")

OBJDIR  := .objects

# Keep the source tree into the objects tree
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.c=.o))

all: mytarget

mytarget: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

# As we keep the source tree we have to create the
# needed directories for every object
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

---

```sh
$ make
mkdir -p .objects
cc -MMD -MP -c main.c -o .objects/main.o
mkdir -p .objects/test
cc -MMD -MP -c test/test.c -o .objects/test/test.o
cc .objects/main.o .objects/test/test.o -o mytarget

$ tree -a
.
├── main.c
├── Makefile
├── mytarget
├── .objects
│   ├── main.d
│   ├── main.o
│   └── test
│       ├── test.d
│       └── test.o
└── test
    ├── test.c
    └── test.h

3 directories, 9 files
```

---

**EDIT**: You can reduce the number of `mkdir` to the minimum by adding the object directory as an [order only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```makefile
# Do not create the directory
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

# Every target finishing with "/" is a directory
$(OBJDIR)%/:
    mkdir -p $@

# Add the "directory/" as an order only prerequisite
$(foreach OBJECT,$(OBJECTS),$(eval $(OBJECT): | $(dir $(OBJECT))))
```

Comment: Wonderful! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Just a little tiny question: `mkdir -p .objects` will be executed many times, it seems that it is executed for each cpp file. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: @Yuhui I found a way which decrease the `mkdir` number. It's a little hack with a `foreach` because you cannot simply add it to the first line, but it is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't edit jmlemetayer's answer, here's how to extend the commands for projects with both C and CPP source:

Firstly to generate the object list, just apply the patsubst twice, once for each extension:

```
SRC_LST := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES)))

OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRC_LST))
```

Then to handle both .cpp and .c files in the implicit rule for compiling:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $$(wildcard %.c*)
    mkdir -p $(@D)
ifeq "$(suffix $<)" ".cpp"
    $(CPP) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
else
    $(CC) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
endif
```

If there is a better way I'm happy to update this.

Comment: Why couldn't you just add a separate rule for .cpp files? Then you wouldn't need to rely on `SECONDEXPANSION` and `$(suffix ...)` trickery.

Comment: @philhord because I tried that and ran into a multitude of errors. At least this works.