# How to make pattern rule that has a 2 folders depth dependency?

Tags: c, makefile

So I have been trying to make a makefile that in a project structured like this:

```
project
 |- bin
 |- src
 |  | main.c
 |  |- test
 |  |  | test.c
 | Makefile
```

I wanted to compile the c files into o files using pattern rules:

```
dir_bin = ./bin
dir_src = ./src

srcs := $(wildcard $(dir_src)/*.c $(dir_src)/*/*.c)
objs := $(addprefix $(dir_bin)/, $(notdir $(srcs:%.c=%.o)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(objs)

$(dir_bin)/%.o: $(dir_src)/%.c
  $(cc) -o $@ $<
```

This would extend to:

```
bin/main.o: src/main.c
```

But if I want to compile the **test/test.c** file, how would I write a pattern rule that also supports source files in a project that has 2 folder depth which would extend to this:

```
bin/test.o: src/test/test.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must keep the source tree in your binary tree in order to be able to use these pattern rules (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43227047/6874310)).

So you Makefile becomes:

```
dir_bin = ./bin
dir_src = ./src

srcs := $(wildcard $(dir_src)/*.c $(dir_src)/*/*.c)
objs := $(addprefix $(dir_bin)/,$(srcs:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all
all: $(objs)

$(objs): $(dir_bin)/%.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(cc) -c $< -o $@
```

And, after compilation, the resulting `bin` directory:

```
$ tree bin/
bin/
└── src
    ├── main.o
    └── test
        └── test.o
```

Comment: You don't HAVE to keep the source tree under `bin`, although it's the best way.  Alternatives are (a) write two pattern rules, one for object files built from `src` files and one for object files built from `src/test` files, or (b) use `VPATH` to tell make where to look for source files.